# Apache run 2 laravel application using Location tag

Tags: laravel, apache

Can we somehow do this. I am showing the example but we can change the below code.

```
<Location />
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app1/public
</Location>

<Location /app2>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app2/public
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i need ex: 192.168.1.23 will open app1 and 192.168.1.23/app2 will
> open app1

In this case you can use the `Alias` directive, like so:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app1/public

        Alias /app2 /var/www/html/app2/public

        # add other directives here
    </VirtualHost>
```

This will map the filesystem contents of `/var/www/html/app2/public` to `/app2` while the default Document Root (`/`) will be `/var/www/html/app1/public`.

I recommend you have a look at the documentation here, it gives a very good explanation for different solutions to your problem: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to laravel. If you want Apache to serve files for 2 different applicatication then set up virtual hosts in the Apache config files

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on ports
Listen 80
Listen 81
Listen 82
Listen 83

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example3"

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:82>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example4"

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:83>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example5"

    # in the 'example5' folder place subfolders 'app1' and 'app2'
    # navigate in the browser to each app i.e. 127.0.0.1/example5/app1 and 127.0.0.1/example5/app2
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: without domain name. Only on IP. What i need 
ex:
192.168.1.23 will open app1
and 
192.168.1.23/app2 will open app1

Comment: Apache needs a way to way to distinguish between requests for different apps. If you don't want to use different domains, you can listen on different ports for each app as shown above.

Comment: do i need to access like 192.168.1.23:82?

Comment: if you don't type a specific port into the browser it will automatically use a default port of 80 or 443

Comment: can i access different folder for different url-segment?
ex: 
/ open /var/www/html/app1

Comment: /app2 /var/www/html/app2

Comment: yes you can access a different folder for each segment, you can place multiple apps in subfolders of a main folder

Comment: can you show in code?

Comment: as shown above in example 5

Comment: thanks, but this is not the optimal way coz i don't want to be in another apps directories. I found solution above. please go throught it once. thanks again buddy.

Comment: same thing, placing a folder for each app inside a main folder...